# MySQL - How to ORDER BY name, then selectively on table by alphanumeric?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to order query results by name, then on a specific table alphanumerically.

This works for all results by alphanumeric:

```
`ORDER BY 'name'+0 ASC"`;
```

But I need only table 'week' sorted alphanumerically, all other results alpha.  I have tried the following but not working:

```
ORDER BY name, week('name'+0) ASC";
```

Table `week` results should be like:

```
Week 1
Week 2
Week 3
Week 4
...
Week10
```

Not:

```
Week 1
Week 10...
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5pBwNx74Qv5u1igxxXy2rN/4)

Comment: Show us table schema, sample input and expected output.

Comment: See updated OP.  Schema shouldn't be necessary as there is no problem with the query itself.

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 But sample data might be needed here.  Also, tell us which version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: You're looking for natural sort.

Comment: @CodeCaster  Correct, but how to do that on one table, otherwise sort on alpha for all other results?

Comment: See updated OP with fiddle

Comment: There are two answers here and the question is closed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For order by clause, you can use custom field like below. For week name field use below in `ORDER BY` clause.

As per our conversation, added one column as `seq` in `select` clause and then based on data we did following `ORDER BY` clause

```
1. Added seq in select clause of all unions.

2. Order by changes:

ORDER BY seq ASC, 
    CASE seq
        WHEN 1 THEN 0 
        WHEN 2 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 6) AS SIGNED)
        WHEN 3 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, -2) AS SIGNED)
        WHEN 4 THEN 0
        WHEN 5 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 6) AS SIGNED)
        WHEN 6 THEN 0
    END ASC,
    name  ASC
```

- First, each union will contain their data as selected i.e. the First query in the union have results at the top and then second and so on.
- In those union, in which `name` is a string, will be not ordered in second `order by` clause, only `year`, `week` and `unit_name` unions are sorted based on number
- Sort all remaining unions by name.

See in [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5pBwNx74Qv5u1igxxXy2rN/9)

Comment: thanks but where do I specify the table 'week'  that needs aphanumeric sorting?

Comment: Show me your complete query just reducing select fields.

Comment: see fiddle in op

Comment: We do have `Year 1` , `Week 1` and some string values in `name` field, how do you want to sort them? Like I got idea about all records with `Week` string but what about others?

Comment: [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5pBwNx74Qv5u1igxxXy2rN/5) do you want this?

Comment: OK, sort tables week, unit and year by alphanumeric and all other tables alphabetically.  Your fiddle works OK on alphanumeric but other results that don't have numeric values are not sorted alphabetically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199601/discussion-between-jitendra-yadav-and-illudiumpu36).